# VS2008 - No Usable Controls in anything other than PocketPC 2003 Platform

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I am trying to create my first Windows Mobile application.

I am using Visual Studio 2008. If I select the platform 'Pocket PC 2003' and go to form view, I get a long list of device controls (e.g. button, CheckBox, ComboBox, etc.).

But if I change the target platform (Project | Change Target Platform) to the 'Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK' I do not get these controls.

It is a fresh install of the Mobile Professional 6 SDK (Refresh version).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Targeting CF 2.0 or 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the same process on my copy of Visual Stuidio 2008 and get the correct results(the toolbox shows). :-\

Sounds like the install of the SDK didn't go complete correctly.

Here's some links that may prove useful:
http://mobiledeveloper.wordpress.com/2007/05/24/windows-mobile-6-sdk-gives-empty-toolbox-in-visual-studio/

http://weimenglee.blogspot.com/2007/12/tip-missing-controls-in-toolbox-visual.html

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have run into this problem?
http://weimenglee.blogspot.com/2007/12/tip-missing-controls-in-toolbox-visual.html

Answer (score 1):

Remembered to stop the debuging after testing your site?

I think the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try that might help anyone facing similar issues:

1. Right-click on the toolbox in Visual Studio and click on 'Show All'. This should display all available controls.
2. If that does not work, right click on the toolbox and click on 'Choose Items'. This should show you all available platforms and controls, from which you can select.

Answer (score 0):

Is it as simple as the "toolbox" is not opening when you switch platforms?

Try View->Toolbox and see if you get the list, Ctrl+Alt+X is the shortcut.

Comment: No, I do see the toolbox, but for the 'Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK' platform it says 'There are no usable controls in this group. Drag an item onto this text to add it to the toolbox'.

If I simply change the target platform to 'Pocket PC 2003', the toolbox then displays a long list of items.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and was able to alleviate it with the following Run command.

devenv.exe /setup /resetuserdata

You lose some preferences but you get to actually use the Toolbox!

Answer (score 0):

i have the exact same problem as 'techboy'
tried deleting toolbox.tbl and etc, same problem, then i tried

cmd /c start /wait devenv /setup /resetuserdata /selfreg /resetskippkgs

as suggested here:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=322223

i seem to have some sql08 compact issue

Comment: unfortunately mine dont seem to work, even after i try re-install the sql08 compact... i seems to have given up trying to get this to work, Im guessing its either my winxp is messed up (as my interop com object cant seem to work on this machine) or i just need to reinstall vs08 again *sigh*